# CordovaCamera options on Karma and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-runner

I'm writing unit tests for my Ionic app and encountered a problem when testing camera related functions. My code uses two global variables set by `cordova.js`: **Camera** and **CameraPopoverOptions**. Since the file only gets inserted on actual mobile devices, both of them are `undefined` when the test needs them. Where should I get these two variables for tests or should I just find out their values and hardcode them?

```
.factory('Camera', ['$q', '$cordovaCamera', '$window', function($q, $cordovaCamera, $window) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      if(!$window.cordova) {
        // We are in dev mode, let's return a kickass Ferrari
        var q = $q.defer();
        q.resolve('/img/ferrari.jpg');
        return q.promise;
      }

      var options = { 
          quality : 75, 
          destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
          allowEdit : false,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 1024,
          targetHeight: 1024,
          correctOrientation: true,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      };      

      // Returns a promise
      return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not change your code by hardcoding the Ferrari in there, but use a mock of $cordovaCamera in your test. You could checkout https://github.com/ecofic/ngCordovaMocks

Or checkout http://cgewecke.github.io/ionic-karma-guide/ for a more practical guide.